# How to clear interval properly in my scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/gna7r4L8/69/)

```
    $(".moving_container").mouseenter(
        function(){
             clearInterval(timer);
        }
    ).mouseleave(function(){
             timer = getInterval(slideWidth,slideHeight,slideLength)
    });
```

I am just trying to create a slider. I want to stop my animations when my cursor is on top of my slider and should resume when cursor leaves the slider.

But it's not working properly.

Steps to produce:
      Resize the screen and mouse hover it. 
      Move the cursor out of the slider.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GopsAB/gna7r4L8/71/)

How do i clear the interval properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue in the code is that the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events are being added with each window resize. I would suggest organizing your code so that the events are attached once. That would require restructuring your code.

A quick solution, however, is to just detach the events before reattaching them:

```
$(".moving_container").off('mouseenter').off('mouseleave');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gna7r4L8/79/)

A better solution would be a complete rewrite though: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gna7r4L8/82/)

Comment: Yes. And I can add it outside the 'Slide Method'. Thanks. Is there any way to improve my code? or is it fine. Thanks

Comment: You could definitely improve the code. Have some consistency about where you place braces and how you space things. It's all over the place right now. Also, you're defining `timer` on window. Don't do that.

Comment: @GopsAB I updated the answer with a rewrite. Although it's not normally the way I would write code (I always do things object oriented), notice the differences between that code and the code in your question.

Comment: Thanks Man. I do follow it in my actual code. Hereafter i 'll follow it everywhere. Thanks.